# Multiple templates in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up a calendar of events using Angular in Wordpress. Files are all connecting correctly, I am just not sure how to set up the template so that I have two views one showing data under a Saturday heading, while the rest is under Sunday.

Here is what I am looking to recreate (this is the same site, using an older setup): http://events.latimes.com/festivalofbooks/the-festival/schedule/

My Angular template works for all the fields, I just dont know how to have that large Saturday show just once with all its related events underneath, followed by another set for Sunday. 
i tried to create a fiddle but it would not work, I am sorry but I just dont have time to troubleshoot it: http://jsfiddle.net/roob/vxfbmsr8/2/

The controller in the fiddle is written so it reads everything right there, alas to no avail. Below are are my actual code, much abbreviated. Sorry if this is lengthy, just want to be clear about the logic, which is why I included a few of the options filter. The choice of table tags are not mine so please ignore.
template/view:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="fobSchContr">
        <h1>Event Directory</h1>
        <label>search: </label>
        <input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search for Authors" autofocus>

        <select class="venues" id="filterTabs" ng-model="artistStage">
            <option value="!!">ALL VENUES</option>
            <option value ="Los Angeles Times Stage" id="lat-stage">LA Times Stage</option>
            <option value ="Cooking Stage" id="cooking-stage">Cooking Stage</option>
            <option value ="Hoy Stage" id="hoy-stage">Hoy Stage</option>
        </select>

        <select class="day" id="filterTabs" ng-model="artistDay">
          <option value='!!' class="all">BOTH DAYS</option>
          <option value ="Saturday" id="saturday">Saturday</option>
          <option value ="Sunday" id="sunday">Sunday</option>
        </select>

        <select class="times" id="filterTabs" ng-model="artistTime">
            <option value='!!' class="all">ALL TIMES</option>
            <option value ="10.00 am" id="10am">10 a.m. - 11 a.m.</option>
            <option value ="11.00 am" id="11am">11 a.m. - Noon</option>
        </select>

          <!-- Calendar BEGIN -->
          <div class="filterWrap" style="border:#FFFFFF thin solid; text-align:">
            <div id="saturdayWrap" >
              <h2 id="saturdayWrap" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter:{value='Saturday'}" {{item.day}} </h2>
              <div class="target-stage stage-only" style="width:100%; border:none;" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter: query | filter: {stage: artistStage, day: artistDay, time: artistTime}">
              <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">          
                <tr>
                  <td class="venue-bar"><h3 style="font-size:16px;"><b>{{item.stage}}</b></h3></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" align="left" valign="bottom" style="color:#356E99; padding-left:20px; text-align:left; border:none; line-height:24px;"><b>Presented by Natural History Museum of Los Angeles</b></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;" >  
                <tr>
                  <td width="190" valign="top" class="ev-time">{{item.time}}</td>
                  <td valign="top" class="ev-desc">
                  <p class="ev-date">{{item.day}}, {{item.date}}, 2015</p>
                  <strong>{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}},</strong> Author of <em>" {{item.work_title}}"</em><br />
                  {{item.stage}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
            myApp.controller('fobSchContr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('wp-content/themes/2015-Festival-of-Books/angular/js/data.json').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.artists = data;
                    //$scope.artistOrder = 'first_name';
                    $scope.artistStage = '!!';
                    $scope.artistDay = '!!';
                    $scope.artistTime = '!!';
                });
            }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an ng-repeat on the `h2` tag, it will be repeated.

```
 <h2 id="saturdayWrap" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter:{value='Saturday'}" {{item.day}} </h2>
```

You might want to have the `h2` by itself, and then repeat content below it.

```
<h2 id="saturdayWrap" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;">Saturday</h2>
<div ng-repeat="item in artists | filter:{value='Saturday'}">
```

--

You could keep it as-is and have an array of 'days' that you repeat over.

On your controller you'd have:

```
$scope.days = ['Saturday', 'Sunday'];
```

And your template

```
          <h2 id="saturdayWrap" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;" ng-repeat="day in days"> {{day}} </h2>
          <div ng-repeat="item in artists | filter:{value=day}">
          <div class="target-stage stage-only" style="width:100%; border:none;" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter: query | filter: {stage: artistStage, day: artistDay, time: artistTime}">
```

Comment: so then if I want another set for Sunday would I just repeat the template, replacing the filter with value='Sunday?'   i need it to follow this format: http://events.latimes.com/festivalofbooks/the-festival/schedule/     you'll have to scroll down the pag to see the Sunday header

Comment: Yes that's correct.  You could make an array of days that you ng-repeat over, which would get rid of duplication in your template.  Something like $scope.days=['Saturday', 'Sunday'].  ng-repeat="day in days", and then use that instead of hardcoding 'Saturday' or 'Sunday' in the template.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. If you do have the time to post an example it would help immensely. I just tried duplicating the template and it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at this, should get you in the right direction http://plnkr.co/edit/i0KNxCdTZHXc9H0fCmRm?p=preview

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I was not ignoring your last post but been working on it. The approach worked on its own but I could not get it to work with my options list. btw thanks for turning me on to Plunker, here's the one I set up:  plnkr.co/edit/iMF4oCz4pUB5XKd0FzU4    something tells me there has to be a way to combine more than one comparator on the one filter but I can not quite connect it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this one.  I modified the way you were filtering days in the outer div, and then referenced aDay instead of artistDay in the inner filter.  http://plnkr.co/edit/3K9YyePPUdR5GvviwuKp?p=preview

Comment: Absolutely beautiful and brilliant, I knew we were real close, thank you so much Nicholas, great timing too as I have to show my project today or tomorrow. I am new to stack and dont have enough reputation or whatever or I would pass on cudos to u. cheers